# About installing windows on a mac

Tags: windows-7, macos

My friend has a MAC OS X 10.7 and wanted to install windows 7, so I gave him the windows installation disk and tried to help him in the process.
The major restriction was that he didn't know his password and we couldn't use  boot camp because of the final driver downloading step.
So I installed windows from scratch, and now it has both OS's, but the problem is that as far as I know the only windows drivers present are the drivers for the keyboard, mouse, usb, and cd(without counting video drivers and such).The core problem is: How can I install the rest of the drivers (internet, sound, etc) with the restriction that I have no password to complete boot camp final step? One idea is to use a 3G portable internet USB to download the drivers with the windows option of automatic driver installation from internet, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be plenty of drivers online, mainly by going to the company's website.  If you forgot the password, you can simply move all the files to a USB drive and restore your computer.

Comment: The mac was sold with the OS included, can i restore it without losing the OS and without the install dvd?

Comment: You might not have to completely restore it, you can restart the whole hardware and the OS would restart.